# Emacs equivalent of Vim's command history (for typed in Meta-x commands)

Tags: vim, command-line, emacs, comparison, history

**Question:** For typed in commands invoked via M-x I am having difficulty understanding how Emacs allows recalling and rerunning the commands. The command-history works quite differently from Vim. It puts the commands in a buffer rather than the "minibuffer".

Is there a way to get something similar to Vim's approach (i.e., previously typed commands can be scrolled through simply using the arrow up-down keys)?

Comment: i'm not sure what emacs you have. but my emacs does that

Comment: Mine too (Aquamacs on OS X). After M-x, up and down keys work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`C-x ESC ESC`, `C-x M-ESC`, or `C-x M-:` puts your history in the minibuffer, after which you can scroll back and forth as you like with the arrow keys.

`M-x list-command-history` puts the whole history in a buffer from which you can execute commands.

`C-x z` repeats the last command.

Look at EMACS manual (info) section [8.5 Minibuffer History.](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html#Minibuffer-History)

Answer (score 4):

M-p and M-n are the canonical history navigation keys in GNU software.  Emacs is no exception; this works nearly everywhere where you can type something.

In the case of extended commands ("M-x commands"), hit M-x, then navigate freely throughout the history.  You can also do a reverse history isearch with C-r, as in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
customize-group minibuffer
```

It will show you an option *History Length* (it's 30 by default here). If you want to save your history across emacs sessions, see

```
customize-group savehist
```

You can use the normal arrow keys <kbd>up</kbd> **`/`** <kbd>down</kbd> to navigate through the history.

Comment: Can someone tell me how the downvote is judged? Changing the history length has a direct effect on being able to scroll through it, doesn't it? I would be glad to fix all errors.